# Interval scheduling - several intervals for each item

Tags: algorithm

Target: to fit into timetable as many clients as possible.
Inputs: each client may have several time intervals when he is free.

For example:

```
client1: [(0, 60), (120, 180)]
client2: [(0, 60), (60, 120)]
client3: [(120, 180)]
client4: [(0, 60)]
```

The output would be:

```
clients:   [client1, client2, client4]
intervals: [(120, 180), (60, 120), (0, 60)]
```

If you really want to show some references or solutions in javascript, you are more than welcome :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What time complexity are you aiming for? What searches have you made before writing this question? People like to say "Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service", it is not an algorithms writing service as well :)

Comment: It's not clear whether your example actually represents the full problem. The example reduces to `{ [1,3], [1,2], [3], [1] }`. The obvious answer is `{client3:3}, {client4:1}, {client2:2}`. If the example *does* accurately demonstrate the problem, then the problem is easily solved with a Sudoku solver. Otherwise, you need to fully describe the problem, and state all of the constraints on the inputs.